# Error in control flow "while" with kotlin

Tags: android, while-loop, kotlin

I have the following code in **JAVA**:

```
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            int total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read( data )) != -1) {
                output.write( data, 0, count );
                total += count;
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / sizeFichero));

            }
```

I am updating my app to Kotlin, but in the WHILE, I have an error.

In this piece of code, I get the following error:

> Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in
>   this context

```
            val data = ByteArray(1024)
            var count: Int?
            var total = 0
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                output.write( data, 0, count!! )
                total += count!!
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / sizeFichero));

            }
```

Any suggestions to eliminate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a work around to your problem:

```
val data = ByteArray(1024)
            var count: Int?
            var total = 0
            while ({count = input.read(data);count }() != -1) {
                output.write( data, 0, count!! )
                total += count!!
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / sizeFichero));

            }
```

For further detail read below discussion:

https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/assignment-not-allow-in-while-expression/339/6

Answer (score 5):

In Kotlin assignments, such as `count = input.read(data)) != -`, cannot be used as expressions, i.e. `count = xy` does not return a boolean and thus cannot be evaluated by `while`.

You can change the code like this:

```
var count = input.read(data)
while (count != -1) {
    output.write( data, 0, count!! )
    //...
    count = input.read(data)
}
```

Also note that Kotlin provides sophisticated means for copying streams:

```
val s: InputStream = FileInputStream("file.txt")
s.copyTo(System.out)
```